# How to get distance from camera to all points in a mesh?

Tags: mesh, scripting, camera

I have an imported mesh and camera is positioned to look at this mesh object. Is there a way to get distance from camera to every vertex(point) in mesh object.

P. S. I want to perform this action in a script, but a link to a User Interface action that performs what I desire wold be helpful too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple Vector Maths**

Blender uses vectors , so this becomes a simple matter of subtracing the global camera location vector from each global vertex location vector. (links)

The global location of the camera is `camera_object.matrix_world.translation`.   The global location of a vertex is its local coordinate (For vertex j in mesh `me` : `me.vertices[j].co`) , multiplied by the matrix world of the mesh object. (`ob.matrix_world`)

Test script, prints the camdist list to system console. `camdist[i]` is the global distance of `me.vertices[i]` from the camera.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

cam = scene.camera
ob = context.active_object

if cam and ob and ob.type == 'MESH':
    camloc = cam.matrix_world.translation
    mw = ob.matrix_world
    me = ob.data # mesh
    camdists = [(mw * v.co - camloc).length for v in me.vertices]
    print(camdists)
```